# vb.net webservice - get full soap xml request

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, web-services, soap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get the raw SOAP request from within a ASP.NET WebMethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587952/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-raw-soap-request-from-within-a-asp-net-webmethod)

I have an ASP/VB.NET webservice.

Some external application is trying to call my webservice.

As soon as my webservice function starts, I would like to get the XML request that was done to call my service / function.

I can't install other applications (such as Fiddler) to monitor the web service... so I need to be able to capture the request through code.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension(VS.80).aspx

Adding the class from the above link, then adding the TraceExtension() _ shown in the code below, now logs both XML soap request and response:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<TraceExtension()> _
Public Function GetResults() as string
 return "True"
End Function
```