# How to read the message from WCF Service in XML format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF Service that has a method GetEmployees(). I need to display the resulting message in **XML format** in a ASP.NET website using *Response.Write* method. What is the easiest way for doing it?

Note: We need to display the complete message; not only the data content

Comment: If GetEmployees() returning List<T> then create one function to generate XML from List<T> by using XMLSerializarion. Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587952/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-raw-soap-request-from-within-a-asp-net-webmethod and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329825/using-linq-to-xml-to-parse-a-soap-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **WCF Test Client**.  Referred the svc url obtained while browsing the svc (http://localhost:1791/CalculationService.svc).  Used **Invoke** operation in the tool. See the  XML tab That gave me the SOAP Envelope.

Do you see any shortcoming with this approach? [Of course I cannot use it in asp.net. But it will meet my current need]

WcfTestClient: Type the “WcfTestClient” command in “Visual Studio Command Prompt”. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx

Answer (score 1):

write own behaviour, you can get soap message before deserialization

implement interfaces `IClientMessageInspector`, `IDispatchMessageInspector` in class attribute, and use it

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/aa717047.aspx)

Comment: I used WCF Test Client. Referred the svc url obtained while browsing the svc (http://localhost:1791/CalculationService.svc) Used Invoke operation in the tool. That gave me the SOAP Envelope.

Do you see any shortcoming with this approach?

Comment: this way suitable for client part only, and you can get this soap message after wcf behaviuor only, WCF Test Client have not behaviour and it's client part therefore you get same data